# Rehosted Workflow Designer throws TypeLoadException upon Load

Tags: c#, wpf, typeloadexception, workflow-foundation-4.5

I'm trying to rehost the workflow designer in my WPF app.

However, when I try to initialise it I get a `TypeLoadException` dialog with the following message:

> "Could not load type
>   'Reporting.Primitives.Documents.IDocField`1' from
>   assembly 'Reporting.Primitives, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

I've tried stripping it down and have gotten to the simple invocation code here:

```
var wnd = new Window();
var grid = new Grid();
wnd.Content = grid;

var met = new DesignerMetadata();
met.Register();

var d = new WorkflowDesigner();
d.Load(new Sequence());
grid.Children.Add(d.View);
wnd.Show();
```

It is the call to `Load` that causes the exception.

Here's the weird part: There's **no** type in the solution called `IDocField<T>`.

There's an `IDocField` and a `DocField<T> : IDocField`, so it seems to be inventing this `IDocField<T>` type from somewhere.

I don't have any reflection calls looking for an `IDocField<T>` either.

I've also tried moving this code around the app into various modules that aren't directly referencing `Reporting.Primitives` to no avail.

There is an `IUiDocField<T>` interface floating around.

Curiously enough, I did write an interface `IDocField<T>` some time ago, but it's not in the solution now, so I don't see why it would be causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual [It's always your (my) fault.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

The app pulls in plugins via a directory using reflection, and it appears there was an old dll in there that was referencing the `IDocField<T>` interface.

It would seem that this wasn't a problem until the workflow designer attempted to probe the assembly for type information that something finally noticed it was referencing something that wasn't there!

**facepalm**